# Oracle- One query to run for multiple timestamps

Tags: oracle

I need a query to for 10 different exact timestamps throughout the day in oracle. For example - for 08:13:33, 09:10:12, 10:14:18

Comment: When you post, **please** proofread what you wrote. *I need a query to [MISSING VERB] for 10 different...* Sorry, we are not mind readers. You need a query to do **WHAT** for 10 different exact timestamps throughout the day?

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for 
tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and code are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Looks like weekend inebriation started early..

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from [YOURTABLE] where [YOURDATECOLUMN] IN (DATETIME1,DATETIME2,DATETIME3....)
```

You probably need to use CAST as well depends on your column type.